# Slick tiledmap render explanation

Tags: java, render, slick

Im trying to render a map for a game I am making using tiled map from the slick class but im having a lot of trouble understanding the difference between the parameters x and y. Below is a googled explanation but im not understanding it

```
public void render(int x,
               int y,
               int sx,
               int sy,
               int width,
               int height)
Render a section of the tile map
Parameters:
x - The x location to render at
y - The y location to render at
sx - The x tile location to start rendering
sy - The y tile location to start rendering
width - The width of the section to render (in tiles)
height - The height of the secton to render (in tiles)
```

My game consists of a car and a camera locked onto it which will follow the car around on the map. The map starts to render as the car move. Could someone give me an explanation on how x and y and sx and sy applies to this.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` function takes a rectangular area of *tiles* and draws them onto a rectangular area of *pixels* on the screen.

- `x` and `y` specify the top left corner of the pixel rectangle
- `sx` and `sy` specify the top left corner of the tile rectangle
- `width` and `height` specify the area of the tile rectangle